# Keeping repoA's commit history after putting a repoA in repoB

Tags: git

I have a GitHub repository named `Coursework`. Also, I have another repo named `ProjectA`. Both repos have a history of commits that I would like to keep, but I want to add `ProjectA` into `Coursework`.

Is there a way to commit the changes in Coursework, but also keeping the commit history from Projects.

Let's say Coursework have the following commits

```
1. Initial commit
2. Add homework 1
```

And ProjectA have the following commits.

```
1. Create project folder
2. Update project.rb
```

So now, after I put the project folder into coursework, I would like all 4 commits to show up in the coursework commit history.

Is that possible? I looked into submodules and it does not seem like what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to merge project-a into project-b:

`cd path/to/project-b
git remote add project-a path/to/project-a
git fetch project-a
git merge --allow-unrelated-histories project-a/master # or whichever branch you want to merge
git remote remove project-a`

It is a duplicate question found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1425892/how-do-you-merge-two-git-repositories). Gotta give credit to Andresch Serj for the answer